# Relationship between entity classes in microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I want to create a simple microservice application in springboot. My project contain 2 services. One of them is userService, the other one is noteService.

For each service, I want to use a schema. These are userService schema and noteService schema. One user creates many notes. There is a one-to-many relationship. I cannot create that relationship between 2 service. I don't understand which columns should tables contain? Do you have any idea? My pojo classes are below:

User.java

```
@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String userName;

    public User(String id, String userName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public User(){

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Note.java

```
@Document(collection = "Note")
public class Note {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String caption;
    private String userNotes;

    public Note() {
    }

    public Note(String id, String caption, String userNotes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.caption = caption;
        this.userNotes = userNotes;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    public void setCaption(String caption) {
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    public String getUserNotes() {
        return userNotes;
    }

    public void setUserNotes(String userNotes) {
        this.userNotes = userNotes;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", caption='" + caption + '\'' +
                ", userNotes='" + userNotes + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What backend datasource are you using? Is it Relational database management  such as postgresql, MySQL or Non-Relational database management e.g MongoDB, Redis, CouchDB etc?

Comment: You didn’t feel it was neccassary to post what database you are using? And what you have tried before posting here?

Comment: did you try referring this - https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: @Dun0523 I want to use MongoDb

Comment: Actually, I want to learn how to create a relationship between 2 service in microservice structure?

Comment: Are you using a relational database or a document based database? Since everything is based on your design in the database.

Comment: I want to use mongodb.I dont know which columns do tables contain in microservice structure.

Comment: It seems you are mixing a fair amount of concepts... you talk of 2 microservices using one single app (i think you actually meant service classes), also with MongoDB you should really refer to collections and documents, no tables. You can refer to this document on how to model what you seek... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: each microservice is a project that was created with  springboot.Actually,If I understand relationship between pojos, database can change as MongoDb or Mysql.It doesnot matter.My problem is User.java class does not see Note type because Note.java is in another project

Answer (score 0):

A service is a layer which facilitates access to your entities via DAO's. So typically you would have a list of DAO's in a service, using which you would access all your entities.

You can have multiple entities in a single service. For details on how to create DAO's and use them, please refer to the [spring-data-mongo guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)